# GsonBuilder - Get Object from Interface

Tags: java, interface, gson

I have a `GsonFactory` declared like this:

```
public class GsonFactory {
    public Gson create() {
        return new GsonBuilder()
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .registerTypeAdapter(MyInterface.class, new MyInstanceCreator())
                .create();
    }

    private static final GsonFactory instance = new GsonFactory();

    private GsonFactory() {
    }

    public static Gson getInstance(){
        return instance.create();
    }
}
```

I also have the `InstanceCreator` class:

```
public class MyInstanceCreator implements InstanceCreator<MyInterface> {
    @Override
    public StrategySymbol createInstance(Type type) {
        return new MyInterfaceImpl();
    }
}

class MyClass {
  private List<MyInterface> myList;

  public List<MyInterface> getMyList() { return myList; }

  public void setMyList(List<MyInterface> myList) { this.myList = myList; }
}

interface MyInterface {
  Long getValue1();
  void setValue1(Long value1);
}

class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface {
  private Long value1;

  @Override
  public Long getValue1() {
     return value1;
  }

  @Override
  public void setValue1(Long value1) {
     this.value1 = value1
  }
}
```

This code seems well implemented, but if I try to parse a `JSON` with `value1`:

```
MyClass obj = GsonFactory.getInstance().fromJson("{'myList': [{'value1':8}]}", MyClass.class);
```

The Object is returned with an instance of `MyInterfaceImpl`, but the field `value1` is always null. As I could see, it seems like `Gson` looks for the fields in the `interface` (none) and not in the `class` implementing the `interface`.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[InstanceCreator](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/1.1/com/google/gson/InstanceCreator.html) can only create instances of a class that does not define a no-args constructor. It does not handle deserialization. Gson still won't be able to figure out the concrete data type of the object.

**Solution. Custom deserializer for interface**

You need to define a custom deserializer for your interface and register this new type adapter in factory.

```java
public class MyInterfaceDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<MyInterface> {
    @Override
    public MyInterface deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
        return jsonDeserializationContext.deserialize(jsonElement, MyInterfaceImpl.class);
    }
}

public class GsonFactory {
    public Gson create() {
        return new GsonBuilder()
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .registerTypeAdapter(MyInterface.class, new MyInterfaceDeserializer())
                .create();
    }
}
```

OR Generic deserializer

```java
public class InterfaceDeserializer<T, E> implements JsonDeserializer<T> {
    private final Class<E> implementationClass;

    public InterfaceDeserializer(Class<E> implementationClass) {
        this.implementationClass = implementationClass;
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
        return jsonDeserializationContext.deserialize(jsonElement, implementationClass);
    }
}

public class GsonFactory {
    public Gson create() {     
        return new GsonBuilder()
                .setPrettyPrinting()                
               .registerTypeAdapter(MyInterface.class, new InterfaceDeserializer<MyInterface, MyInterfaceImpl>(MyInterfaceImpl.class))
                .create();
}
```

OR

```java
public class MyInterfaceDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<MyInterface> {
    @Override
    public MyInterface deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
        MyInterface myInterface = new MyInterfaceImpl();
        JsonObject jObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        myInterface.setValue1(jObject.get("value1").getAsLong());
        return myInterface;
    }
}

public class GsonFactory {
    public Gson create() {
        return new GsonBuilder()
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .registerTypeAdapter(MyInterface.class, new MyInterfaceDeserializer())
                .create();
    }
}
```

**Another option**
Use [RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.danilopianini/gson-extras/0.2.1/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.html) but this solution requires an extra `type` property in json to define the exact subtype, see the documentation.

Example:

```java
    public Gson create() {
        RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<MyInterface> runtimeTypeAdapterFactory = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.of(MyInterface.class).registerSubtype(MyInterfaceImpl.class, "MyInterfaceImpl");
        return new GsonBuilder()
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .registerTypeAdapterFactory(runtimeTypeAdapterFactory)
                .create();
    }
```

JSON must contain type field:

```json
{
  myList: [
    {
      value1: 8,
      type: MyInterfaceImpl
    }
  ]
}
```

Please note [gson-extras](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson-extras/2.8.5) library required for that option. This artifact is located at [CronApp](https://artifactory.cronapp.io/public-release/) repository.

Comment: Hello Eugene, thank you for such detailed answer. Certainly, a ``CustomDeserializer` is the way to go.